# Compiler error when trying to RenderPartialAsync with a simple ASP.NET Core website

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

#### Summary

I am wanting to correct my use/calling of the `RenderPartialAsync` method while trying to render an ASP.NET Core partial view.

#### Details

I'm trying to render a partial view in my simple ASP.NET Core 5.0 website:

```
<td>
    @await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Listings", item.Listings);
</td>
```

When I try the following, I keep getting a compiler error:

[image]

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'
```

I don't understand what it's trying to complain about. I'm *guessing* that this method awaits a Task which doesn't return anything ... but it's wanting something to be returned?

I thought that the [`RenderPartialAsync` method will render the contents to the response stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperpartialextensions.renderpartialasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0) *inside* that method... not return some HTML which I then need to do something, with.

> In this context, "renders" means the method writes its output using Writer.

What am I doing wrong? Is it the placement of my razor 'code snippet' start/end code block or something?

Also, I tried using the `Html.RenderPartial` (notice this is the SYNC method) and I got a warning about how this blocks AND also the same error message.

### Update #1

> What is the return type of `item.Listings`

Answer: `IEnumerable<Listing>`

Comment: Does `_listings` view or result exists without errors? could you share it too?

Comment: What's the return type of `item.Listings`?

Comment: @Pribina oh good question! I have no idea if it's causing any errors ... but those would be runtime errors, no? it doesn't have any compiler-errors... or at least the compiler isn't complaining. Just to confirm, i've removed -all- the content from that partial view and just had a div with some hard coded text.

Comment: @user1986237 - good question - i've updated the post with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had to change the code from:

```
<td>
    @await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Listings", item.Listings);
</td>
```

to

```
<td>
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Listings", item.Listings);
    }
</td>
```

I don't understand *why* but this now works.

My *guess* is that `@await <stuff>` is TWO commands, not one .. so it needs to get handled differently. While `@{ stuff }` is a code block *section*.

But the proper answer should be to use Tag Helpers instead.

so this:

```
<td>
    <partial name="_Listings" model="item.Listings" />
</td>
```

Comment: Your guess is correct: [`Html.RenderPartialAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.htmlhelperpartialextensions.renderpartialasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0) returns a `Task`, so the result type is `void`. The `@` without braces asks Razor to render the result, which is not possible: There is no way to convert `void` to anything renderable. This would only be the right way to go if `Html.RenderPartialAsync` returned a `string`, which needed to be rendered manually. The braces introduce a new code block, which allows standard C# syntax.